# scroll sync between two views in Android

Tags: android

I am working on some project in which i required below functionality.

1) One semi circle on the top of the screen in inverted position with some items.

2) below this screen, I have one view pager

Required : when I scroll view pager (from one page to another), it semi circle should also scroll accordingly, and when pager view changes from one position to another, semi circle item should also change from current to next item.

I shall appreciate if i get a piece of code
suggestions welcome.

Comment: Could you show us what you have been trying to do so far?

Comment: How to add an image. can you share your email so that i can send you drawing?

Comment: Please check this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHCgl.png